# Aligning explanation with equations

Tags: formatting

I'm currently trying to write a solutions manual. In order to make it look a lot more neater I'm trying to organise the solutions into columns in a box (using mdframed with multicols).

Here's what I've right now. Is there any way to align the explanation with the equations? I've tried text and intertext but it doesn't really seem to work.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{markdown}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{questions}
 
\question A man of mass $60kg$ stands on a weighing machine, which is placed on the floor of a lift. When the lift is moving upwards with an acceleration of $0.5ms^{-2}$, the reading of the weighing machine would be? (Take $g = 10ms^{-2}$)

  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice $570N$
    \choice $600N$
    \choice $605N$
    \choice $630N$
    \choice $770N$
  \end{oneparchoices}

\noindent \textbf{Solution:}

\begin{mdframed}
\begin{multicols}{2}

Consider the man as a system. 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\text{By }\sum \vec F &= m \vec a\\
N - mg &= ma\\
N &= mg + ma\\
N &= 60(10+0.05)\\
N &= 630(N)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\columnbreak

\includegraphics{Q2_1.png}

\end{multicols}
\end{mdframed}


\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that can be copied and pasted and compiled as is (i.e., starts `\documentclass{...`, loads all the necessary packages and defines the necessary commands, etc. Could you also explain a but more what you mean by "align" here? The image is taller than the equations. Should they be aligned at the top, centered vertically relative to it, something else?

Comment: Does using `\newcolumn` instead of `\columnbreak` do what you want?

Comment: I'm not trying to align the image here, I'm just trying to center align the column on the left, like you can see a line of text explanations followed by a string of equations, I'm trying to center align those two.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I know what you mean, but does `\begin{center}` before the explanation and `\end{center}` either right after it, or after the end of the equation (these are slightly different w/r to spacing) do what you want?

Comment: Welcome. // I suggest to add some clarifications which are now in the comments to the question. This way your problem statement will be more complete in the place where it should be.

Comment: I think that the equation are already centered in the column...

Comment: @frabjous That works like a charm! But I have another problem now (*facepalm).

Comment: So, I have the explanation and the equations lined up now, but there's currently a large chunk of space between the explanation and the equations. I assume this is because the image is a lot taller than the equations. In this case, are there any ways to let the equations follow the explanation immediately?

Comment: It's probably stretching to fill the available space because  you used `\columnbreak`. Try using `\newcolumn` instead. (Another option would be to use `\raggedcolumns` before the multicols environment)

Comment: You might also look at paracol.  It can make the columns different widths.

Comment: Hi, just to update, I've solved everything by using `\vfill\null` before `\columnbreak`, thanks for the help!